# How do I run a Docker container as a non-root users and still be able to use ssh?

Tags: docker, ssh-keys

Stackoverflow told me to post this here...

I created a CentOS 7 based docker container (using Dockerfile) that contains everything I need to perform my tasks (git clone ssh://... and make). The results are written to a shared volume (the shared volume is the checked out source code so the are there by default) so they will be available to the host. I was only able to accomplish this by making sure the container user's uid and gid match the host user's uid and gid (e.g. both are myuser 1000:1000). If the uid and gid don't match I get permission errors writing to the shared volume. The container has a .ssh folder that holds the user's private key.

I've been tasked to eliminate the necessity to have the 2 users match. I added --user $(id -u):$(id -g) to the docker run command line and I can write to the shared volume fine but this breaks the ability to access our git repository assuming there is no longer any ssh key association (getting >> Please make sure you have the correct access rights...).

How can I have a container that doesn't have a dependence on matching users, I can fully write to a shared volume and also have it retrieve my source code via ssh?

**UPDATE:**

Just added  -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro to the docker run command but the container now runs as the wrong user.

Host:
user_a 1000:1000
user_b 1001:1001

/home/user_a (1000:1000)
/home/user_b (1001:1001)

Container:
user_b 1000:1000

/home/user_b (1000:1000)

When I normally run the container is is running a user_b (1000:1000)
Cannot access host stared because UID and GID don't match

When using --user 1001:1001 I can write to the shared volume fine but cannot access /home/user_b because UID and GID don't match

When using  -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro the running user is user_a (because contianer is 1000:1000 which is mapped to user_a)

When using both -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro --user 1001:1001 I get a whoami error: cannot find name for user ID 1001 and access denied to /home/user_b

Comment: Check the ownership and permissions on the shared volume .ssh directory and its files.

Comment: I hadn't shared the .ssh folder (seems a security risk) but did so (as -v /home/<user>/.ssh:/home/<user>/.ssh:ro) and still getting permissions error.

Note the user is already there just a different uid/gid.  This causes a permission denied as well when trying to access the user home directory as the difference.

Comment: If your process in your container can't access the ssh private key then it can't use it to log in to your git repo. Of course it really should have its own keypair, rather than using someone else's.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544282/what-is-the-best-way-to-manage-permissions-for-docker-shared-volumes has several approaches listed for the issue. My favourite is Alex Myznikov's answer, where he shares host `/etc/passwd` with the container, therefore syncing host users with container users. The general problem here is that internally Docker just reads / writes files with UIG/GID using kernel functions, and there isn't UID/GID conversion possibility on that interaction.

Comment: Updated question with results